# NullPointerException al actualizar en JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Tengo el siguiente código para actualizar los valores de un objeto que se muestran en una tabla:

```
public class AgendaJPADAOImpl implements AgendaJPADAO, Serializable {

EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("AGENDAJPAPU");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    public void actualizar(Contacto c, int id) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.find(Contacto.class, id);
        em.merge(c);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

El siguiente código es la clase donde realizo las operaciones con el método actualizar y otros:

```
package comm.agendaJPA.controlador;

import comm.agendaJPA.dao.factory.AgendaJPAFactory;
import comm.agendaJPA.dao.interfaces.AgendaJPADAO;
import comm.agendaJPA.interfaz.*;
import comm.agendaJPA.modelo.Contacto;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;

public class AgendaJPAControlador implements ActionListener {

private final AgendaJPAFactory factory = new AgendaJPAFactory();
private final AgendaJPADAO agendaDAO = factory.agendaJPAFactory();
private final AgendaJPAdmin agendaJPAdmin;
private final AgendaJPAContacto agendaJPAContacto;
Contacto contacto = new Contacto();
FuncionesControlador funciones = new FuncionesControlador();

public AgendaJPAControlador(AgendaJPAdmin agendaJPAdmin, AgendaJPAContacto agendaJPAContacto) {
    this.agendaJPAdmin = agendaJPAdmin;
    this.agendaJPAContacto = agendaJPAContacto;
}

private enum Componentes {
    getTxtBuscar_Contacto,
    getBtnAgr_Contacto,
    getTablaContactos,
    getSubmenu_Modificar,
    getSubmenu_Eliminar,
    getBtnGuardar,
    getBtnModificar
}

public void limpiarCampos() {
    this.agendaJPAContacto.getTxtNombre().setText("");
    this.agendaJPAContacto.getTxtApellido().setText("");
    this.agendaJPAContacto.getTxtMovil().setText("");
    this.agendaJPAContacto.getTxtCasa().setText("");
    this.agendaJPAContacto.getTxtPersonal().setText("");
    this.agendaJPAContacto.getTxtTrabajo().setText("");
    this.agendaJPAContacto.getTxtPanelDireccion().setText("");
}

public void abrirAgendaJPA() {
    this.funciones.listarTabla(agendaJPAdmin.getTablaContactos());
    this.agendaJPAdmin.setTitle("AGENDA");
    this.agendaJPAdmin.setLocationRelativeTo(agendaJPAdmin);
    this.agendaJPAdmin.setVisible(true);

    this.agendaJPAdmin.getTablaContactos().addMouseListener(this);
    this.agendaJPAdmin.getTxtBuscar_Contacto().addActionListener(this);
    this.agendaJPAdmin.getTxtBuscar_Contacto().setActionCommand("getTxtBuscar_Contacto");
    this.agendaJPAdmin.getBtnAgr_Contacto().addActionListener(this);
    this.agendaJPAdmin.getBtnAgr_Contacto().setActionCommand("getBtnAgr_Contacto");
    this.agendaJPAdmin.getSubmenu_Modificar().addActionListener(this);
    this.agendaJPAdmin.getSubmenu_Modificar().setActionCommand("getSubmenu_Modificar");
    this.agendaJPAdmin.getSubmenu_Eliminar().addActionListener(this);
    this.agendaJPAdmin.getSubmenu_Eliminar().setActionCommand("getSubmenu_Eliminar");
    this.agendaJPAContacto.getBtnGuardar().addActionListener(this);
    this.agendaJPAContacto.getBtnGuardar().setActionCommand("getBtnGuardar");
    this.agendaJPAContacto.getBtnModificar().addActionListener(this);
    this.agendaJPAContacto.getBtnModificar().setActionCommand("getBtnModificar");
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) {

    switch (Componentes.valueOf(evento.getActionCommand())) {

        //Eventos ventana AgendaJPAdmin
        case getBtnAgr_Contacto:
            this.limpiarCampos();
            this.agendaJPAContacto.setTitle("NUEVO CONTACTO");
            this.agendaJPAContacto.getBtnModificar().setVisible(false);
            this.agendaJPAContacto.getBtnGuardar().setVisible(true);
            this.agendaJPAContacto.setVisible(true);
            this.agendaJPAContacto.setLocationRelativeTo(agendaJPAdmin);
            break;

        //Eventos JPopupMenu de la ventana AgendaJPAdmin
        case getSubmenu_Modificar:
            this.limpiarCampos();
            this.agendaJPAContacto.setTitle("MODIFICAR CONTACTO");
            int filaSeleccionada = this.agendaJPAdmin.getTablaContactos().getSelectedRow();

            if (filaSeleccionada >= 0) {

                List<Contacto> contactosMod = agendaDAO.extraerTodos();
                Contacto contactoMostrado = contactosMod.get(filaSeleccionada);

                this.agendaJPAContacto.getTxtNombre().setText(contactoMostrado.getNombre());
                this.agendaJPAContacto.getTxtApellido().setText(contactoMostrado.getApellido());
                this.agendaJPAContacto.getTxtMovil().setText(contactoMostrado.getMovil().toString());
                this.agendaJPAContacto.getTxtCasa().setText(contactoMostrado.getCasa().toString());
                this.agendaJPAContacto.getTxtPersonal().setText(contactoMostrado.getPersonal());
                this.agendaJPAContacto.getTxtTrabajo().setText(contactoMostrado.getTrabajo());
                this.agendaJPAContacto.getTxtPanelDireccion().setText(contactoMostrado.getDireccion());

                this.agendaJPAContacto.setLocationRelativeTo(agendaJPAdmin);
                this.agendaJPAContacto.getBtnGuardar().setVisible(false);
                this.agendaJPAContacto.getBtnModificar().setVisible(true);
                this.agendaJPAContacto.setVisible(true);

            } else {
                //No se ha implementado nada
            }
            break;

        case getSubmenu_Eliminar:
            int filaEliminar = this.agendaJPAdmin.getTablaContactos().getSelectedRow();

            if (filaEliminar >= 0) {
                int opcionEliminar = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(agendaJPAdmin,
                        "Desea eliminar este contacto?", "Borrar", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

                if (opcionEliminar == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    List<Contacto> contactos = this.agendaDAO.extraerTodos();
                    Contacto contactoEliminar = contactos.get(filaEliminar);

                    if (contactoEliminar != null) {
                        this.agendaDAO.borrar(contactoEliminar);
                        this.funciones.listarTabla(this.agendaJPAdmin.getTablaContactos());
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(agendaJPAdmin, "No se pudo eliminar el contacto");
                    }
                } else {
                    //No se ha implementado nada
                }
            }
            break;
        case getBtnGuardar:
            String nombre = agendaJPAContacto.getTxtNombre().getText();
            String apellido = agendaJPAContacto.getTxtApellido().getText();
            String movil = agendaJPAContacto.getTxtMovil().getText();
            String casa = agendaJPAContacto.getTxtCasa().getText();
            String personal = agendaJPAContacto.getTxtPersonal().getText();
            String trabajo = agendaJPAContacto.getTxtTrabajo().getText();
            String direccion = agendaJPAContacto.getTxtPanelDireccion().getText();

            String contactoNuevo = nombre + apellido + movil + casa + personal
                    + trabajo + direccion;
            if (contactoNuevo != null) {
                this.agendaDAO.guardar(new Contacto(nombre, apellido,
                        Integer.valueOf(movil), Integer.parseInt(casa),
                        personal, trabajo, direccion));
                this.funciones.listarTabla(this.agendaJPAdmin.getTablaContactos());
            } else {
                //No se ha implementado nada
            }
            this.limpiarCampos();
            this.agendaJPAContacto.dispose();
            break;

        case getBtnModificar:
            int filaMod = this.agendaJPAdmin.getTablaContactos().getSelectedRow();

            if (filaMod >= 0) {
                String nombreMod = agendaJPAContacto.getTxtNombre().getText();
                String apellidoMod = agendaJPAContacto.getTxtApellido().getText();
                String movilMod = agendaJPAContacto.getTxtMovil().getText();
                String casaMod = agendaJPAContacto.getTxtCasa().getText();
                String personalMod = agendaJPAContacto.getTxtPersonal().getText();
                String trabajoMod = agendaJPAContacto.getTxtTrabajo().getText();
                String direccionMod = agendaJPAContacto.getTxtPanelDireccion().getText();

                List<Contacto> contactos = agendaDAO.extraerTodos();
                Contacto contactoMod = contactos.get(filaMod);

                int id = contacto.getId();
                this.agendaDAO.actualizar(new Contacto(nombreMod, apellidoMod,
                        Integer.valueOf(movilMod), Integer.parseInt(casaMod),
                        personalMod, trabajoMod, direccionMod), id);

                this.funciones.listarTabla(this.agendaJPAdmin.getTablaContactos());
                this.agendaJPAContacto.dispose();
                this.limpiarCampos();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Mi clase **Contacto**, que es el **POJO** del programa es esta y de donde busco el id del contacto al querer actualizar el objeto es la siguiente:

```
package comm.agendaJPA.modelo;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Calendar;

@Entity(name = "ContactoAgenda")
@Table(name = "contacto")
public class Contacto implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "fecha")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Calendar fecha;
@Column(name = "nombre")
private String nombre;
@Column(name = "apellido")
private String apellido;
@Column(name = "movil")
private Integer movil;
@Column(name = "casa")
private Integer casa;
@Column(name = "personal")
private String personal;
@Column(name = "trabajo")
private String trabajo;
@Column(name = "direccion")
private String direccion;

public Contacto() {
}

public Contacto(String nombre, String apellido, int movil, int casa, String personal, String trabajo, String direccion) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.movil = movil;
    this.casa = casa;
    this.personal = personal;
    this.trabajo = trabajo;
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Calendar getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(Calendar fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}

public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

public Integer getMovil() {
    return movil;
}

public void setMovil(Integer movil) {
    this.movil = movil;
}

public Integer getCasa() {
    return casa;
}

public void setCasa(Integer casa) {
    this.casa = casa;
}

public String getPersonal() {
    return personal;
}

public void setPersonal(String personal) {
    this.personal = personal;
}

public String getTrabajo() {
    return trabajo;
}

public void setTrabajo(String trabajo) {
    this.trabajo = trabajo;
}

public String getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

}
```

Al realizar las operaciones muestra este **printStack**:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at comm.agendaJPA.controlador.AgendaJPAControlador.actionPerformed(AgendaJPAControlador.java:192)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

La línea 192 que menciona el printStacke es esta:

`int id = contacto.getId();` **Aquí busco el id del contacto**

En vez de buscar el *id* del objeto yo mismo podría pasarle *filaMod* al método y funcionaría pero el anterior objeto sigue estando presente cuando lo hago, ergo, no se actualiza, solo se guarda nuevamente esta vez con los nuevos valores.

Comment: donde defines la varialble `em` utilizada en  `public void actualizar(Contacto c, int id) {` y podrías poner el código de la linea 192 de la clase AgendaJPAControlador

Comment: @Joacer, ya actualicé la pregunta

Comment: La variable `contacto` no se ve que la hayas asignado en ningún momento. Eso debe ser lo que te da `null` o nos falta código para ayudarte.

Comment: Tienes razón no el método no la visualiza, es que la tengo mas arriba para cubrir otros métodos, pero a pesar de, me sigue dando el error, déjame actualizar la pregunta con la variable **contacto**.

Comment: ① ¿`agendaJPAdmin` está estrechamente relacionado con JPA o sólo es la vista? Entonces, ¿para qué la parte `JPA` en sus nombres? Lo mismo con `agendaJPAContacto`.  ② ¿La fábrica `EntityManagerFactory` se crea una única vez o múltiples veces? Crear la fábrica es un proceso *costoso*. ③ ¿Cómo sabes que `filaMod` corresponde exactamente con un *índice* de la lista? ¿No sería mejor guardar el `id` del `Contacto`  seleccionado? ④ ¿`AgendaJPADAO` tiene múltiples implementaciones o sólo una? ⑤ Si ya tienes JPA, ¿por qué implementar el patrón de diseño DAO?

Comment: @Paul Vargas1. `agendaJPAdmin y agendaJPAContacto` son vistas, `agendaJPADAO` esta estrechamente relacionado con JPA. 2. `EntityManagerFactory` se crea una sola vez y luego se instancia **(em)** para las demás funciones. 3. No estoy totalmente seguro pero cuando activo el modo **Debugg** me da los mismos índices que la lista, si por su puesto por eso es que estoy buscando el **id** del contacto con `int id = contacto.getId();`. 4. Solo se implementa en los métodos de una sola clase, por tanto tiene varias

Comment: Tengo una clase `Controlador` que gestiona todos **Listeners** de las ventanas, es como especie de **MVC**, déjame actualizar la pregunta con esto para que puedan entender

Comment: Creo que debe de faltar algo más de código, justo encima de donde te marca el error haces un `new Contacto()` y asumo que es el constructor por defecto con lo que todos los valores que tenga serán siempre null (ya que no veo que le asignes ningún valor).

Comment: Si no pones el código del constructor `Contacto()` no podemos ayudarte. También sería importante el código de `getId()`. Entre esos dos tienes el problema.

Comment: @Raider utilizo la variable **contacto** para obtener el **id** del contacto seleccionado y luego lo paso como parámetro al método **actualizar**

Comment: @DavidCalderon pero cuando creas la variable contacto esta se crea vacia (tal y como está en tu código). Si declaras un objeto y usas su constructor por defecto y este no hace nada, todas sus variables serán null siempre, de ahí el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como puse en los comentarios, tu problema es que cuando haces `Contacto contacto = new Contacto();` las propiedades de este siempre serán `null` (a menos que lo inicialices pasándole los parámetros con el otro constructor que tienes o le hagas un `setId()`). Con el código que tienes creo que esto te podría funcionar:

```
List<Contacto> contactos = agendaDAO.extraerTodos();
Contacto contactoMod = contactos.get(filaMod);
contactoMod.setNombre(agendaJPAContacto.getTxtNombre().getText());
contactoMod.setApellido(agendaJPAContacto.getTxtApellido().getText());
contactoMod.setMovil(Integer.valueOf(agendaJPAContacto.getTxtMovil().getText()));
contactoMod.setCasa(Integer.parseInt(agendaJPAContacto.getTxtCasa().getText()));
contactoMod.setPersonal(agendaJPAContacto.getTxtPersonal().getText())
contactoMod.setTrabajo(agendaJPAContacto.getTxtTrabajo().getText());
contactoMod.setDireccion(agendaJPAContacto.getTxtPanelDireccion().getText());

this.agendaDAO.actualizar(contactoMod, contactoMod.getId());
```

Incluso, si lo haces de esta forma podrías cambiar el método actualizar y mandarle solo el objeto contacto, que ya contiene el id que necesitas

```
public void actualizar(Contacto c){
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.merge(c);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Con JPA no deberías necesitar el método find para actualizar un registro ya que al mandarle el objeto contacto este debería actualizarlo correctamente al tener el mismo id

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es que nunca asignas un id antes de leerlo. Tienes que usar `setId()` antes de usar `getId` o añadir un constructor que le asigne valor. Al usar `new Contacto()` y poner justo despues `contacto.getId()` se encuentra con una variable no inicializada.

O haces eso o se te ha olvidado traerte la variable `contacto` cargada desde otro sitio.

Comment: Le añadí esta parte de código en esta parte: `int id = contacto.getId() this.contacto.setId(id);`, claro, debajo de la línea, pero me sigue dando **NullPointerException**

Comment: El problema es que `getId()` nunca te podrá dar ningún valor porque no lo tiene. No sé como tienes montada tu agenda, pero en algún sitio debes tener el `id` y debes recogerlo para actualizar tu contacto. Primero mira dónde está tu contacto, si es una fila de una tabla, un campo de un formulario, o cualquier otra cosa con la que hayas cargado el contacto previamente en tu agenda, que está modificando el usuario y que quiere guardar cuando le da al botón de tu caso `getBtnModificar` en el `switch` que has hecho. Normalmente con el método que usas `evento.getActionCommand()` debes de saberlo.

Comment: Es en una tabla, no se como recoger el `id` de la manera como dices, porque si no lo puedo buscar de la clase contacto, pues no se de donde sacarlo, lo único que se me ocurre es esto `int id = contactos.get(contacto.getId());`, pero ya debes saber que me debe dar error pues un objeto no se puede convertir a un primitivo, crees que puedes darme un ejemplo por favor, no tienes que resolver el problema con ella puede ser con cualquier otro caso.

Comment: Necesitaría ver cómo cargas la agenda para ver donde va a parar cada dato, o cómo elige el usuario el contacto para editar, es decir, de todos los que tienes cómo escoge uno en concreto.

Comment: Cuando dices "cómo carga" te refieres a la clase de conexión que tengo o al método que utilizo para cargar los contactos en la tabla

Comment: Me refiero a cómo cargas la GUI que luego usa el usuario. Supongo que será un contenedor con varios componentes (botones, una tabla, campos de texto, etc...) alguno de ellos servirá para elegir un contacto en concreto y le rellenera los campos con los datos actuales y que luego el usuario quiere modificar y guardar. Por ahora sólo conozco la clase `Contacto` y un `Listener` con lo que hace. Necesito el código de la agenda en sí, que será un JFrame o algo parecido.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47425/discussion-between-david-calderon-and-awes0mem4n).